# YouTube and SoundCloud embedding is now enabled

Tags: discussion, soundcloud

It is now possible to embed YouTube and SoundCloud content in posts here.

#### Embedding Video or Audio

1. Upload the content you want to embed to YouTube (for video/audio) or SoundCloud (audio only).
2. When composing your post, paste the URL to the uploaded audio or video in the body, on a line by itself, like so:

   > I'm trying to reproduce this performance...
   >
   > http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vin9sapwkRU

   or

   > I can't quite capture this sound...
   >
   > http://soundcloud.com/cyrilic/nintendo-super-mario-bros-ground-theme
3. After you save the post, it will be rendered with an embedded player of the appropriate type:

[image: YouTube player]

[image: soundcloud player]

You can see some examples of this in action at

- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/record-a-video-without-static-noise
- [How important is it to have an eq pedal in your chain?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/how-important-is-it-to-have-an-eq-pedal-in-your-chain)

Comment: This rocks. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that when you sign up for [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com) (it's free!) none of the audio samples you upload will be public by default.

**You must manually enable the clips you upload to be visible to the public for them to work here!**

So when uploading to SoundCloud, look for the public / private toggle, and make sure it is enabled.

[image]

After uploading, this can also be toggled on the track page by clicking the "share" button on the audio widget itself.

[image]

The share dialog will indicate whether the track is currently public or private; click **Make track public** to ensure it can be shared here.

[image]

Once you do that, simply paste the URL to the SoundCloud page for the audio clip on a line by itself, like so:

`http://soundcloud.com/jatwood/fallout-opening-theme-maybe`

*this isn't enabled on meta, but works on the main site :)*